# Would syntax highlighting compatible with other languages than C# be worthy?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, syntax-highlighting

Over the current year, I have written more code in VB.NET than C#. Hence, my code samples were obviously Visual Basic.

I have noticed some bad syntax highlight with this language, particularly when inserting comments in code sample, (otherwise the highlight is great), which seems to be parsed as a string of text by the code sample parser or syntax highlighter of SO, call it what you want, I don't actually know the exact technical term for this.

While I understand that SO cannot offer syntax highlight for every single existing programming languages, I am wondering whether this would be doable to provide some sort of syntax highlighter such as ones provided in *Notepad++*, for example.

What I mean is that one could choose, while editing his/her question/answer, the language highlighting that suits best for the code sample he/she provides. Indeed, C# would be the default.

That said, would syntax highlighting compatible with other languages than C# be worthy?

Comment: Lol, *other languages than C#*, [errr...?](http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/README.html#langs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax highlighting does not parse the code blocks as anything in particular. Instead, it uses a set of heuristics that are reasonable correct in a pretty big set of more-or-less common languages. In fact, most of the heuristics are for c-like languages, which is why c# comes out pretty well.

In any case, c# is not being given special treatment and visual basic is not being ignored---it simple is wonky enough that general purpose heuristics don't work well with it.

Answer (score 1):

It gets wonky on VB.NET comments.  Fix that and it will look okay.  Like this:

```
Sub Test()
'' double quotes are okayish
End Sub
```